# How to know whether parameter "whatif" has been passed to a customer cmdlet programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-cmdlet

I would like to know whether whatif parameter has been passed to a cmdlet.

for ex: remove-mycmdlet -whatif

I tried to do it by finding  the value of the variable: **WhatIfPreference**.

But its always yields false.

Can you please let me know how can i know whether whatif parameter is passed in?

Thank you very much,

Regards,
Naresh

Answer (score 0):

When I define function like that:

```
function Test-WhatIf {
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $true)]
param (
)

    $WhatIfPreference
    $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('WhatIf')
}
```

I get $false or $true, depending on the addition of -WhatIf to the command.
Although this is just advanced function, I would not expect different behavior in compiled command... Are you sure you've implemented SupportsShouldProcess correctly?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. This is custom cmdlet i implemented in .net (c#). How can i do it programmatically? basically i used "PSCmdlet's object GetVariableValue(string name)". It always returned false. Btw, is there any equalent in c# for $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('WhatIf') ?

Comment: Yes, i thing i implemented the supportsshouldprocess correctly as confirm/whatif parameters are working as expected when user passes them. i declared my cmdlet with following attributes set:  [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Remove, "EmcLun",
        SupportsShouldProcess=true, ConfirmImpact=ConfirmImpact.High)] Its just that i need to know user has passed these parameter, but dont know how to do it programmatically in .net.

Comment: OK, grabbed VS and tried to find the same in "proper" cmdlets. You will find my answer on the second thread... :)